# xPath parameter in `getNodesAsync` is not working as expected

Tags: office-js, word-addins

[`getNodesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.customxmlpart?view=word-js-preview#getnodesasync-xpath--options--callback-) has a parameter called `xPath` which I think should help me to query my custom XML. I think it is malfunctioning because it only returns the node when I pass an `*`. Any other path (even if it exists), returns an empty array.

[image]

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Click `Run` to add the xml

```xml
<AP xmlns="accordproject.org">
  <template xmlns="acceptance-of-delivery">
    <shipper>Aman Sharma</shipper>
  </template> 
</AP>
```

2. `Get node` is supposed to fetch the nodes at `/AP/template`.
3. `Delete XML` will delete the customXML.

Link to ScriptLab snippet: https://gist.github.com/algomaster99/fc10bc8fcf3429f1d3ad1fbadaa3216f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found how this works. It seems that for the custom XML parts that are created with the Common Office JavaScript APIs (as distinct from Custom XML Parts created in the Word-specific JavaScript APIs), Office assigns default aliases for the namespaces in order: `ns0`, `ns1`, etc. You have to use these in the xpath variables. So in your gist, if you change the first parameter of the call to `getNodesAsync` to `"/ns0:AP/ns1:template"` it works.

Comment: This works for me too. Thanks!
I would like to add one thing to the answer. Every XML node must have a unique namespace (xmlns) for `getNodesAsync` to work.